# Why all the radio button can be checked in same time?

Tags: php, html

I have create an array that contain 4 element and I want to make a loop using for to display 4 radio button to each element in the array .it's worked but I can check all my radio button in the same time how to fix this issue?

my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php


 $Realisateurs=array(" James Cameron", " David O. Russell", " Woody Allen" , " Michael Haneke");

?>

<?php
 for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
 {
     ?>
     <input type="radio" name"group1" value="<? $Realisateurs[$i] ?>"><?php echo $Realisateurs[$i] ?><br> 
     <?php

 }
 ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

result:
[result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RInku.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name"group1" value="<? $Realisateurs[$i] ?>"><?php echo $Realisateurs[$i] ?><br>
```

Replace with:

```
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="<? $Realisateurs[$i] ?>"><?php echo $Realisateurs[$i] ?><br>  // you missing the equal sign after name
```

missing `=` sign at `name"group1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Error Was there.

 - name"group1" should be name="group1"
 - value="" here, you are not echoing. Echo value here. Otherwise null will get printed.

 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
         $Realisateurs=array(" James Cameron", " David O. Russell", " Woody Allen" , " Michael Haneke");
         for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
         {?>
             <input type="radio" name="group1" value="<?echo $Realisateurs[$i];?>"><?php echo $Realisateurs[$i]; ?><br> 
         <?}?> 
    </body>
    </html>
```